# Is it ok to send xmlhttprequest to a server every second?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, gmail

I am creating a Chrome extension that checks gmail inbox.

I'm using the xml feed url to fetch it:
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom

For updating, I'm using chrome.alarms API that sends GET request every 10 seconds. Is that too much? If not, could I change it to 1 second too? How much load does their server have to handle in order to send me the feed's information?

Comment: Using XHR every 10 seconds looks like not bad idea, but everysecond might be too much. Each XHR request new connection, sending lots of data  to server, and lots of data will receive. If you need a real-time app, please consider to using Websocket or Socket.io instead of XHR. They are very lightweight, very fast and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I will look into it. Since there are no other answers, could you make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Notification APIs (gmail seems to have them)

You can get updates with a lot less latency if you use [a different technique such as "long polling" or "web sockets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). This is very useful for things where you want no lag, like a real-time chat, a web-based video game, or a time-sensitive process like an auction or ticket/order queue. It might be a bit less important for something less real-time, like email (see the last paragraph in this answer).

[Gmail seems to have an API that is explicitly designed for fast notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

---

#### HTTP polling

Most web servers can stand up to being called once a second without killing their site. If they can't, then they have some serious security problems ([Denial of Service attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), or worse if their site is buggy enough to suffer data loss when overloaded).

Google has big servers, and protection, so you don't really need to worry about what they can handle, as long as they don't block you. Google may rate limit calls to their gmail API, and you may end up getting a user throttled if you call their API more then they prefer. [Consult their documentation to find out what their rate limiting policies are](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota).

To more generically answer you question, normal HTTP isn't really optimized for frequent polling for refreshed data. You *can* make a decent number of requests (even upwards of one a second or more). You probably won't kill the computer or browser or even make them run slowly, as long as the request and response payload data is small enough, and the processing/dom changes you do with the response are minimal when the data comes back unchanged.

Assuming you don't violate per-site rate limits, and have small data payloads in the request you are making, then the biggest problem is that you might still be wasting a lot of bandwidth. For people who have to pay by the minute/megabyte, this is a problem. This is much more frequent in Europe than in the United States (although it is also frequent on cellular devices).

Consider if you really need email to be checked every second. Would every ten seconds be fine? Maybe every minute? Maybe your app could do a refresh when you send mail, but take longer to check for new mail when it is idle? Think about what use cases you are solving for before assuming everything always has to be constantly updated. What would waiting a few extra seconds break? If the answer is nothing, then you can safely slow down your updates. If there are use cases that would be broken or annoying, then figure out why it is important. See if there are even better ways to address that use case, or if updating frequently is actually the right answer. Sometimes it is!

Comment: Thank you very much for your lengthy, informational answer! I have much to learn and this will help me greatly.

Comment: @Slayther - I tend to write a lot. Glad it's helping :) Cheers!

Comment: One question, though. You say checking for email is not so important to use real time methods, such as long polling, but rather use push API. If I were to start implementing updates for Facebook, Twitter, Stack Overflow, news sites, weather data, etc., Would long polling still be an 'overkill'?

Comment: @Slayther My comments are definitely in the think-about-it category, rather than a recommendation. Try to figure out what makes sense for how people are going to use your app, and build around that intended use. Maybe that's frequent checks, maybe that's infrequent checks. Imagine what work they'll be doing with what you're building, and how often they're going to even notice a few extra seconds. If it is "all the time", then see if you can update more frequently to keep it speedy.

Comment: @Slayther As for `long polling`, it is a bit of a confusing name. In your current design, you are "polling", and if you did it infrequently it might seem like "long polling". That's not the right thing to call it though. "long polling" refers to a specific technology that uses HTTP to do a low-latency push from the server to the client. They do this by leaving the connection until there is new data to send to the client, then immediately sending it. That way the server doesn't have to wait for the client to loop and request the data again before it can push it out.

Comment: Ohh, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Long polling requires the server to be designed to support it. The client doesn't require any new technology and can use Ajax. It is written like a normal looping poll. The client just needs to make sure it only sends one request to the server at a time, even though the request may take minutes or more to complete (since the server keeps it open until there is data).

Comment: Now that makes even more sense! Haha, took me a while to understand what you really meant. I'm still new in all this web technology when it comes to servers and communication from client to server.

Answer (score 3):

Using XHR every 10 seconds looks like not bad idea, but every second might be too much. Each XHR request creates new connection, sending lots of data to server, and lots of data will receive. If you need a real-time app, please consider to using Websocket or Socket.io instead. They are very lightweight, fast and easy to use.

Comment: Each XHR request may not require a new connection if HTTP keep-alives are enabled.

Comment: Technically, you are correct. But HTTP not designed for real-time communication. Websocket is designed for.

Comment: Yes, that's besides the point. I just wanted to point out the flaw in the statement that each HTTP request is a new connection.

Comment: I know what do you want to talk to me, but keep-alives option is available from HTTP 1.1, so in other means, you were wrong. You should be say "In **HTTP 1.1**, new connection will not created if keep-alives enabled.